# Passing Data Through GLSL Shaders

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, geometry-shader

I'm having some trouble passing data through my shaders, notably the Geometry shader. I've never used a Geometry Shader before so I'm having a little trouble understanding the way it passes data.

Basically, before the Geometry shader, I'd pass data from the Vertex Shader to the Fragment simply using in/out qualifiers. Like I'd have:

Vertex Shader!

```
out vec3 worldNormal;
out vec3 worldView;
```

Fragment Shader:

```
in vec3 ex_worldNorm;
in vec3 ex_worldView;
```

So, for the Geometry Shader, would I have to do something like this to pass data?

```
in vec3 ex_worldNorm[];
in vec3 ex_worldView[];

out vec3 ex_worldNorm[];
out vec3 ex_worldNorm[];
```

My question is, how do I pass data between each Shader properly? Like, is this the way to do it? (because it's not working for me!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unbounded arrays for the input are correct for a Geomtery Shader (the size will be determined by input type in the layout qualifier), but the output ***cannot*** be an array.

You output vertices one at a time by writing values to all of the output variables and then calling `EmitVertex (...)`. Any output variable that is not written to between calls to `EmitVertex (...)` will be undefined.

---

#### Here is a very simple example Geometry Shader that does what you want:

```
#version 330


layout (triangles) in; // This will automatically size your two arrays to 3, and also
                       //   defines the value of `gl_in.length ()`

in vec3 worldNormal [];
in vec3 worldView   [];

// ^^^ Names match up with Vertex Shader output


layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;

out vec3 ex_worldNorm;
out vec3 ex_worldView;

// ^^^ Names match up with Fragment Shader input


void main (void)
{
  // For each input vertex, spit one out
  for (int i = 0; i < gl_in.length (); i++) {
    ex_worldNorm = worldNormal [i];
    ex_worldView = worldView   [i];
    EmitVertex ();
  }
}
```

Comment: and `max_vertices` is how many vetrices are allowed to be output by the geometry shader.